# Ruby array - returning a collection of duplicate and non-duplicate objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, logic

I have an array of Race objects with the following attributes:

- way
- race_period_id
- track_id

I want to collect those Race objects -- where the way and track_id attribute values are the same -- in a new array called plural_array. (Basically, each duplicate Race object as defined by way and track_id.)  In another array called singular_array, I want to collect all those Race objects that are non-duplicates.

For example, let's assume that I have four Race objects with the following attribute values:

race1:

- way = 1
- race_period_id = 20304
- track_id = 94949

race2:

- way = 2
- race_period_id = 20888
- track_id = 94949

race3

- way = 1
- race_period_id = 20899
- track_id = 94949

race4

- way = 1
- race_period_id = 20888
- track_id = 885858

So here I have two "plural" objects: race 1 and race3.  And two "singular" objects: race2 and race4.

If I had a method called **get_plural_and_singular_arrays(races_array)**, what algorithm would I use to return a **plural_array** (containing only objects race 1 and race3)  and a **singular_array** (containing only objects race2 and race4)?

```
def get_plural_and_singular_arrays(races_array)
  # algorithm here

  return plural_array, singular_array
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might start by using `group_by` and then organizing the results of that into singles and doubles:

```
list.group_by do |i|
  [ i.way, i.track_id ]
end.values.group_by do |list|
  list.length > 1
end
```

You should have a hash with the keys `true` and `false` for your multiple entries and single entries respectively.

Comment: +1 for a nice functional solution. I would use partition, though: list.group_by { |r| [r.way, r.track_id] }.partition { |ary| ary.size > 1 }

Comment: Btw my one-liner (with `ActiveSupport` array enhancements): `list.group_by { |i| [i.way, i.track_id] }.partition(&:many?)`

Comment: neat trick...i tried it out...at first, thought it might be little too "cute", but it works out quite well

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def get_plural_and_singular_arrays(races_array)
  singular_array, plural_array = [], []
  # algorithm here 
  races_array.group_by { |race| [race.way, race.track_id] }.each do |key, values|
    if values.size == 1
      singular_array << values[0]
    else
      plural_array += values
    end
  end
  return plural_array, singular_array
end
```

Test:

```
irb(main):025:0> Race = Struct.new(:way, :track_id)
=> Race
irb(main):026:0> r1 = Race.new(1, 2)
=> #<struct Race way=1, track_id=2>
irb(main):027:0> r2 = Race.new(1, 2)
=> #<struct Race way=1, track_id=2>
irb(main):028:0> r3 = Race.new(3, 4)
=> #<struct Race way=3, track_id=4>
irb(main):029:0> r4 = Race.new(3, 5)
=> #<struct Race way=3, track_id=5>
irb(main):030:0> get_plural_and_singular_arrays([r1, r2, r3, r4])
=> [[#<struct Race way=1, track_id=2>, #<struct Race way=1, track_id=2>], [#<str
uct Race way=3, track_id=4>, #<struct Race way=3, track_id=5>]]
irb(main):031:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
def get_plural_and_singular(races)
  grouped_races = races.group_by { |r| [r.way, r.track_id] }.values
  grouped_races.partition { |grp| grp.size > 1 }.map(&:flatten)
end
```